# Can't boot into Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: uefi, boot-repair

I've tried installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode on my PC using USB which already has windows 10 in it, but the problem is:

I'm unable to boot into my Windows 10. Moreover Ubuntu has not installed...
I've tried many tutorial videos on YouTube one of them is updating `grub`, but it is displaying in terminal that AUFS error.

Please help me in solving this issue.

It shows the below mentioned steps as soon as I started my PC:

1. Start PXE over IPv4 .press[esc] to exit
   after typing exit it again shows the thing mentioned below
2. Start PXE over IPv6 .press[esc] to exit
   It shows the below mentioned commands:

   ```
   failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi-not found
   failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi-not found
   failed to start MokManager:not found
   ```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1076674/edit) to include this information, please do not use comments to list out information such as this

Comment: What brand/model system. Do you have UEFI boot on, but UEFI Secure Boot off. Have you set USB as UEFI bootable in UEFI? PXE boot may be a UEFI boot option which is for network boot. You do not want or need that. See  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI